# How to stream two live streams to internet on pi cams?

Tags: raspicam, pi-zero-w, pi-a+

OK, so I'm thinking about a animal wildlife camera trap. I was wondering...how do I stream two cams from a pi zero W? I can get an other pi (most likely a+) and have the a+ to give video input to the zero w via usb cable or ethernet, that serves it up in a simple webpage. I followed this simple tutorial here http://www.toptechboy.com/tutorial/raspberry-pi-zero-model-w-tutorial-2-making-a-wireless-portable-ip-camera/
So I was wondering if I can do it with two cams. I am planning to use noir and normal cams by the way. (incase it makes a differance in setup.)

Comment: This question gave me an idea. I'll try to make a 3D camera using two cameras.

Comment: Nice, but do you have any idea on how to?

Answer (score 3):

I had a positive experience with **RPi camera** (Noir or normal) together with one small **USB camera**. It was quite (resources) expensive, but RPi3 was ok with that.

I have used https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer

In the directory mpjg-streamer was installed:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./;./mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -y 630x480 " -o "output_http.so -w ./www -p 8080`

and for the raspberry I used this:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./;./mjpg_streamer -i "input_raspicam.so  -hf -vf -x 1024 -y 768 -mm matrix -fps 3 " -o "output_http.so -w ./www -p 8088"`

These commands I run using two times `screen` (like `screen -S rpi` and `screen -S usb`) to be able to log out and leave them running. 
You can play with options the options for both camera (`-y` on usb enables most of cams with yuv mode, `-d` is sometimes needed.).

I have even a complicated script with a loop that starts cams, but I doubt it is mature enough to be widely used. You have the output as http on  ports 8080 and  8088.